# Error on reassigning workflows in FileNet

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet-process-engine

I am currently developing some Javacode that reassigns workflows that belong to a case in a FileNet 5.0 system.

In some cases I get the following error in the logs:

> [FNRPE2131090209E]WorkObject Operation is not valid in this context.
>    WorkObjectOperation is only valid when an instruction sheet interpreter update function is called. That happens when a WobUpdateUnlocked occurs. In any other case, this exception is thrown. for

If I google the error I only find a few hits that specify this error but it does not give a clear reason to what is the situation for this error.

It is thrown when I execute the `vwWorkObject.doReassign()` call.

Does someone know what the state is that is causing this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as it turns out this exception means that your workflow is in either a waitfor or delay condition before comming to an assign step. 
This took me a while to figure out, but in my case it means that I can just ignore this situation, as there is no need for a reassign as the system is going to do it for me as soon as the workflow reaches the assign step.